# Is this simple proof of Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem acceptable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ProofWiki, a [very simple proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem#Proof_5) of the CBS theorem is presented, using the following lemma:

If $T \subseteq S$ and $f: S \to T$ is an injection then there is a bijection $h: S \to T$.

And there is a rather [lengthy proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem/Lemma) of the lemma.

The following proof is an attempt to find a simpler proof of the lemma.

Define $C = \{f^k(x) | k \in \mathbb{N}, x \in S \setminus T \}$.

Clearly,  $C = C_0 \cup C_1$, where:

$C_0 = S \setminus T$,

$C_1 = \{f^k(x) | k \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}, x \in S \setminus T \}$.

Note, that $S \setminus C_0 = T$.

Obviously, $im(f|C) = C_1$.

Define a mapping $h: S \to S$ as follows:

$h(x) = \begin {cases} f(x) & : x \in C \\ x & : x \notin C \end {cases}$

Note, that $dom(h) = S$.

Clearly, $h = f|C \cup id(S \setminus C)$, where $id(S \setminus C)$ is the identity function on the set $S \setminus C$.

$im(h) = im(f|C) \cup im(id(S \setminus C) =$
$C_1 \cup (S \setminus C) =$
$C_1 \cup (S \setminus (C_0 \cup C_1)) =$
$S \setminus C_0 =$
$T$.

Also, $h$ is an injection because $h$ is the union of the injections $f|C$ and $id(S \setminus C)$ and $dom(f|C) \cap dom(id(S \setminus C)) = \{\}$
and $im(f|C) \cap im(id(S \setminus C) = C_1 \cap (S \setminus C) = \{\}$ because $C_1 \subseteq C$.

Now $h$ is a bijection $S \to T$  because $dom(h) = S, im(h) = T$, and $h$ is an injection.

Is this proof acceptable or what should be changed, for example, add a reference to the literature that a piecewise function is the union of its subfunctions?

Comment: Are you including $0$ in your definition of $\mathbb N$? [If not I don't follow how your $C_0$ is a subset of $C.$]

Comment: I would emphasize that $C_0$ and $C_1$ are disjoint (you use this fact in the equality $C_1 \cup (S \setminus (C_0\cup C_1)) = S\setminus C_0$). Your proof is also not much different from the one on the Wiki; the notation is a bit different, but it's largely the same logic (and you also skip some steps --- for example working in elementary set theory one would need to define $C$ rigorously using recursion, which you hide by referring to $f^k$)

Comment: @D.R. But $C$ is defined rigorously not using recursion. Maybe I should state that $f$ is a function from $S$ to $S$ - to allow the notation $f^k$.

Comment: @coffemath Yes, 0 is a natural number.

Comment: No, if you look at the original proof the rigorous definition uses recursion. The issue is that there's no way to define $f^k$ other than recursion. Maybe if you've already set up the notation it's valid, but then you'd have to cite where someone set up that notation.